# Multiple "it" inside "describe" when writing Jasmine Test (BDD)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am currently writing a test in Jasmine, using Karma as a JS runner.  Can there be multiple "it" inside a "describe" like below:

```
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function() {
      var scope = {},
          ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);

      expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(2);

    it('should create "greetings" models with 3 greeting', funciton(){
      var scope = {},
        ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);

      expect(scope.greetings.length).toBe(3);

    });
    });
  });
});
```

It currently fails, but how do you write a test without being redundant (in this case, having to describe the same controller, twice)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `beforeEach` function to create common setup.  It can be added at any level.

```
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {
  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){
    beforeEach(function() {
      this.scope = {};
      this.ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);
    });

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function() {
      expect(this.scope.phones.length).toBe(2);
    });

    it('should create "greetings" models with 3 greeting', funciton(){
      expect(this.scope.greetings.length).toBe(3);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but the OP says 'this test fails'.

regardless of ForEach() being needed, could that be because:

```
 expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(2);
```

should be:

```
 expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(**3**);
```

Comment: That the test fails is utterly tangential to the problem the OP was aiming to solve. Users of Mocha make tests fail *on purpose*. The OP was clearly not baffled by the fact that the test failed but by how to avoid duplicating code across tests.

Comment: @Louis - +1 for teaching me a new word. :-)  
Tangential - adjective
1. pertaining to or of the nature of a tangent; being or moving in the direction of a tangent.
2. merely touching; slightly connected: tangential information.
3. divergent or digressive, as from a subject under consideration: tangential remarks.
4. tending to digress or to reply to questions obliquely.